# Activate Office (Word, Excel and PP) document from windows form application

Tags: winforms, 64-bit, office-interop

I have been working with Office since 1995 and every time there is a new version there is problem with activating document from other application. Now I am there again.

I am working with VS 2017 C# Office 2016 64 bit

It is a C# Windows Form application for templatemanager together with SharePoint. I am starting the template with ex.

```
bool YesNo = IsExcelFileOpened();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelObj;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook ExcelVbookObj;
    if (YesNo==false)
    {
        ExcelObj = new App();
    }
    else
    {
        ExcelObj = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
    }
    ExcelObj.Visible = true;
```

---

```
    public bool IsExcelFileOpened()
    {
        bool isExist = false;
        System.Diagnostics.Process[] prs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process pr in prs)
        {
            if (pr.ProcessName == "EXCEL")
            {
                isExist = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return isExist;
    }
```

I have tried with;

1 the normal office command like Visisble Activate

2 the use of [DllImport("user32.dll")]

```
public static void FocusWindow(IntPtr focusOnWindowHandle)
{
    int style = GetWindowLong(focusOnWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE);

    // Minimize and restore to be able to make it active.
    if ((style & WS_MINIMIZE) == WS_MINIMIZE)
    {
        ShowWindow(focusOnWindowHandle, SW_RESTORE);
    }



    uint currentlyFocusedWindowProcessId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), IntPtr.Zero);
    int appThreadint = GetCurrentThreadId();

    uint appThread = Convert.ToUInt32(appThreadint);

    if (currentlyFocusedWindowProcessId != appThread)
    {
        AttachThreadInput(currentlyFocusedWindowProcessId, appThread, true);
        BringWindowToTop(focusOnWindowHandle);
        ShowWindow(focusOnWindowHandle, SW_SHOW);
        AttachThreadInput(currentlyFocusedWindowProcessId, appThread, false);
    }

    else
    {
        BringWindowToTop(focusOnWindowHandle);
        ShowWindow(focusOnWindowHandle, SW_SHOW);
    }
}
```

If I start my application from ex Word and from the application start a Excel template Word is still on top when the Exel document is opened.

Please give me some help.

Ola

Comment: I havent been working with Office in a while, and have been using the NetOffice library but I can remember minimizing + maximizing the application helped sometimes in order to bring it to front. `ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.WindowState = wdWindowStateMinimize` and `ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize`

Comment: Yes, I remember we could do that, but it didn't work in this environment. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: There is much that you do not show that you state you tried, but in regards to the window minimizing/restore operation, I recommend that it is performed on the reference to the Excel application (see: [ApplicationClass.WindowState Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.applicationclass.windowstate?view=excel-pia)) as opposed to the windows of the workbook.